# The TextInput in my app make my keyboard permanently laggy

Tags: android, react-native, android-softkeyboard, react-native-textinput

The TextInput of my react-native app make my phone keyboard laggy even when i turn off the app. It works normaly until i try to type fast, it cause my keyboard slow and laggy. Worse yet, now my keyboard is permanently slow even though the app isn't running or after I clear the app's cache. The only way to make it normal is restart the phone. Is it a bug?

```
<Portal>
        <Dialog visible={props.visible} onDismiss={hideDialog} style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', borderRadius: 10 }}>
            <Dialog.Title style={{ borderBottomWidth: 1, borderBottomColor: 'grey' }}>Report</Dialog.Title>
            <Dialog.Content>
                <TextInput
                    maxLength={500}
                    numberOfLines={10}
                    multiline={true}
                    autoFocus={true}
                    theme={ReportDialogTheme}
                    mode="outlined"
                    label="Reason"
                    placeholder="Reason for reporting"
                    value={inputReason}
                    onChangeText={text => setInputReason(text)}
                    selectionColor={THEME_SECONDARY}
                />
            </Dialog.Content>
            <Dialog.Actions style={{ backgroundColor: THEME_PRIMARY, borderBottomLeftRadius: 10, borderBottomRightRadius: 10 }}>
                <Button onPress={hideDialog} mode='text' color="white">Cancel</Button>
                <Button onPress={report} mode='text' color="white">Submit</Button>
            </Dialog.Actions>
        </Dialog>
    </Portal>
```

The TextInput was imported from react-native-paper

Comment: can we see any code for your TextInput

Comment: i've just updated my code, please check it

Comment: can we see your setInputReason function

Comment: it's just a hook state: const [inputReason, setInputReason] = useState('');